# Is Hyperledger Explorer compatible with Hyperledger Fabric v2.0.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I've build a Hyperledger Fabric network (v2.0.0) and I want to know if Hyperledger Explorer tool is compatible with this version of network.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As of now regarding Hyperledger, Hyperledger Explorer can support up to Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.8
Ref:- https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#10-release-notes----

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. As of July 1st 2020 they support v2.0 and above.
Just download the latest docker image build of version: v1.1.1 (Jul 17, 2020) and you are good to go.